# Singing Mashiv Haruach

Tags: tefilla, simchat-torah, geshem-tal-ruach, chazaka

[The Shulchan Aruch and Rama pasken in Orach Chaim Siman 114:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.114.9?lang=bi) that if one says Mashiv Haruach (or doesn't say Mashiv Haruach) 90 times (with the surrounding words) we assume he made a Chazaka and will continue to say it the correct way.

> אם ביום ראשון של פסח אומר ברכת אתה גבור עד מוריד הטל צ' פעמים כנגד ל' יום שאומר אותה ג' פעמים בכל יום משם ואילך אם אינו זוכר אם הזכיר גשם הרי הוא בחזקת שלא הזכיר גשם ואינו צריך לחזור: הגה וכן לדידן אם אמר עד מכלכל חיים בלא משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם שמזכירין בימות הגשמים וכן אם אמר בשמיני עצרת צ' פעמים אתה גבור עד מוריד הגשם אם נסתפק אחר כך אם הזכיר או לא חזקה שהזכירו [דעת עצמו]:‏

The Mishna Berura there says you should say it 101 times ideally:

> מא) צ' פעמים - ובתשובת חתם סופר חא"ח סימן כ' מורה ובא לכתחלה לאומרו מאה פעמים ואחד אמנם בדיעבד מי שאמר רק תשעים פעמים אין בידינו לפסוק שיחזור ויתפלל נגד פסק השו"ע:‏

Based on this many Shuls have a custom on Simchas Torah to sing 101 times the words "מחיה מתים אתה רב להושיע - משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם." ‏

In the [Otzar Hachochmah forums](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=36832) there is a big argument whether it works to sing it as singing may not be relevant to saying it normally as [Tosfos on Baba Kamma 37a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Bava_Kamma.37a.5.1?lang=bi) says that a Chazaka can't be established from Shabbos onto weekday because on Shabbos we wear different clothes.

> הרי הוא מועד לשבתות. מפרש בירושלמי לפי שראה אותם במלבושים נאים אחרים וחשובים בעיניו נכרים ואינו מכירם:‏

This seemed fascinating to me. Many Shuls led by many great Rabbanim sing it on Simchas Torah with the assumption that it will create a habit for saying it normally, but it is a good point. Why should it create a Regillus that will allow you to assume that when you Daven Shmoneh Esrei normally you will say it the correct way.

Comment: Is there a question here? Everyone already knew that saying it 100 times in a row isn't the same as saying it in prayer 100 days. Clearly people that rely on singing it think it's similar enough.

Comment: "many Shuls" I've been to many shuls on Simchat Torah over many years. I have not seen one shul do this. Where have you seen this?

Comment: No problem. Rav Yitzchak Ezrachi, Rav Yitchak Zilberstein, Rav Meir Soleveitchik, Rabbi Yisroel Janowski, Rav Charlap, and many others did it in their Shuls/Yeshivos.

Comment: @Eliyahu Did any of them actually rely on the singing to not go back in Shmoneh Esrei if they forgot? Or were they just singing to be silly? It's hard to imagine anyone actually relies on this. It's completely obvious that singing 100 times doesn't actually change what you will say by default in Shmoneh Esrei.